# Numpy Matrix multiplication Maximum in Linear space

Tags: python, numpy, memory, numpy-ndarray

I have two big arrays `A` is `n x k` and `B` is `k x m`.

I would like to compute `np.argmax(A @ B, axis=1)`, that is the maximum column of each row.

Unfortunately, if I do this naively, numpy will compute the entire array `A @ B`, which requires `n x m` memory -- more than I have.

It should be possible to do this with no extra memory, just computing each entry individually and keeping the maximums.

Is it possible to do this in numpy?

Comment: Questions like "Is it possible to do this in numpy?" are not great. Yes, it's *possible*, you already described how, so what's stopping you? I think you are asking if numpy implements any lazy matrix multiplication, which I don't think it does. You are going to have to write out the logic yourself. Also, do you mean linear *space*? I don't know of any linear time matrix multiplication algorithms.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga My mistake, I naturally meant linear space. What's stopping me is the quadratic space requirement of the approach I described. I can write out the logic with python loops, but that removes the performance benefit of using numpy.

Comment: Right. Unfortunately, I don't think `numpy` implements what you want (not 100% sure). But, you could try to use `numba`, a JIT compiler for numpy-based code. Note, the naive algorithm is slower, algorithmically, than what `numpy` may be using under the hood, and indeed, is likely optimized in various arcane ways depending on the quality of the BLAS/LAPACK backend. But the naive, yet lazy, approach may be right for you. Fortunately, `numba` is very good at speeding up loop-based code so I'd give it a shot if I were you

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments numpy can't do exactly what you want.  However, if you have enough memory you could iterate over the rows of `A` and do the matrix multiplication piece-wise, collecting the argmax for the resulting `1xk`in each iteration of the loop.   This would be sort of a compromise between using numpy fully and rolling your own implementation from scratch.  Something like the following.  You could as use numba for a little speed boost.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

a = np.random.randn(500,200)
b = np.random.randn(200,1000)

def max_by_row(a,b):
    out = np.zeros((a.shape[0],),dtype='int64')
    for idx in range(a.shape[0]):
        out[idx] = np.argmax(a[idx,:] @ b)
    return out
        
@jit        
def max_by_row_jit(a,b):
    out = np.zeros((a.shape[0],),dtype='int64')
    for idx in range(a.shape[0]):
        out[idx] = np.argmax(a[idx,:] @ b)
    return out
```

Comparing times:

```
%timeit np.argmax(a@b,axis=1)
4.6 ms ± 226 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit max_by_row(a,b)
12.2 ms ± 233 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit max_by_row_jit(a,b)
8.85 ms ± 135 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you. Numba is pretty interesting. I don't think it will be sufficient for me this time though, but I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the [`vq` function in `scipy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.vq.html). It takes two matrices, `A` and `B`, and for each row `a` of `A` it tells you which row of `B` is closer.

This saved me a factor 20 in time, not even considering memory, for my case, in which `B` has about a million rows.